# Laravel 5 ManyToMany

Tags: php, laravel

I have a many to many relationship set up so that a client can be tagged. When I store the client I'm also associating the tags with them using:

```
foreach($tags as $v) {
  if (!empty($v)) {
    try {
      $client->tags()->create(['title' => $v]);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
      // doesn't work for already existing tags :(
      if ($e-> getCode() == 23000) {
        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['title' => $v]);
        $client->tags()->attach($tag->id);
      } else {
        throw $e;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found that when using `$client->tags()->create();` causes a duplicate key error if the tag already exists (I have a unique key set up for title) so I've had to catch the exception and use another method to relate the client and tag.

Although what I have does work, I feel there must be a more elegant way to do this but haven't been able to find a solution with my Google-fu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
My previouse response was for HasMany. My apologies. Here is my correct response:

Simply reorder what you are doing and use the `firstOrNew` method. First-or-new won't create and therefore won't assign an ID until the model is saved. You can then test for the ID to know if you need to save the association. Something like this:

```
$tag = Tag::firstOrNew(['title' => $v]);
if(!$tag->id){
    $tag->save();
    $client->tags()->attach($tag->id);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I get; Unknown column 'client_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: I have updated my answer. I apologize for the error.